# Datepicker visible glitch?

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

http://jsfiddle.net/s6Umb/

I'm getting this strange behavior where when I create a datepicker, there appears a small div right below the picker:

```
<div 
    id="ui-datepicker-div" 
    class="ui-datepicker ui-widget 
           ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
</div>
```

This div seems to become the actual calendar display when I click on the datepicker input, and becomes hidden when I am done... but is visible upon initialization.

Is this a known issue, or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this is a [known glitch](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-datepicker-initial-display-none-fixup).  Don't know why it hasn't been resolved until now, but the easiest way to fix it is to just add the following CSS to your global stylesheet:

```
#ui-datepicker-div
{
    display: none;
}
```

I've done this on several projects and it's worked perfectly without any problems.

Comment: Just for your information: I am actually having problems with this solution. I am using "datepick" (this is an other jQuery plugin for selecting date ranges) and datepick is not working if you use this proposed fix.

Comment: For me also works if in file `file jquery-ui.js` to `this.dpDiv = datepicker_bindHover($("<div id='" + this._mainDivId + "' class='ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all'></div>"))` add `.css("display", "none");` But with css seems better, because after some time may update/replace file `file jquery-ui.js` and must remember to add `.css("display", "none");`